# undefined method `_s_path' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined

I'm getting an `undefined method` error when trying to create a new "ad" in my app.

form:

```
<div class="row">
<%= form_for @advertisement do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter Title " %>
</div>
```

routes (both controller and model names are singular):

```
resources :advertisement
```

rake routes :

```
    advertisement_index GET    /advertisement(.:format)          advertisement#index
                    POST   /advertisement(.:format)          advertisement#create
  new_advertisement GET    /advertisement/new(.:format)      advertisement#new
 edit_advertisement GET    /advertisement/:id/edit(.:format) advertisement#edit
      advertisement GET    /advertisement/:id(.:format)      advertisement#show
                    PATCH  /advertisement/:id(.:format)      advertisement#update
                    PUT    /advertisement/:id(.:format)      advertisement#update
                    DELETE /advertisement/:id(.:format)      advertisement#destroy
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `advertisements_path'
```

please help me out I have tried a few things and nothing seems to work. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `resources :advertisements` will give you `advertisements_path`

Comment: and for your code you have `advertisement_index_path`

Comment: so i should make advertisement plural ? cause ive tried that and it work but then i get another error once i try to save the ad.

Comment: It should be plural, post the other error here! :)

Comment: So I changed it to `resources: advertisements` and now I get  `No route matches [GET] "/advertisement/new"`

Comment: now all routes will be plural sir...`/advertisments/new`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="row">
<%= form_for @advertisement, url: advertisement_index_path do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter Title" %>
</div>
```

Comment: I get `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"advertisement"} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: Change it to url: advertisement_index_path

Comment: This worked! Thank you! i kept `resources: advertisement`  the same and  I added `<%= form_for @advertisement, url: advertisement_path do |f| %>` and it worked perfectly . My question now is , why did I have to change it to `advertisement_index_path` in order for it to work properly?

Comment: Please refer the guides. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Answer (score 1):

Controller name should be plural... `AdvertisementsController` in `advertisements_controller.rb`

Routes should be plural... `resources :advertisements`

Model should be singular... `Advertisement` in `advertisement.rb`

Comment: I realized that after i had created the controller and  I didnt know how to fix it so I figured id roll with it but now its causing me some issues.

Comment: Ah, right.. well, just change the first line of the controller from `AdvertisementController` to `AdvertisementsController`and rename the file from `advertisement_controller.rb` to `advertisements_controller.rb`  ... your editor should be able to do that or you can do it in Terminal

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you want to keep the format of singular you can set the path of the form with:

```
<%= form_for @advertisement, url: advertisement_path do |f| %>
```

Preference in Rails is to make your controller plural, so resources :advertisements and AdvertismentsController.

As you have already created it, you can change your resources to:

```
resources :advertisements, :controller => 'advertisement'
```

This gives:

```
advertisements GET    /advertisements(.:format)  advertisement#index
               POST   /advertisements(.:format)    advertisement#create
new_advertisement  GET    /advertisements/new(.:format) advertisement#new
```

So you will now point at advertisment controller

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with having a singular controller name, although it's generally against [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :advertisements, path: "advertisement" #-> url.com/advertisement/new

#config/routes.rb
resources :advertisement, controller: :advertisements #-> url.com/advertisement/new

#config/routes.rb
resource :advertisement #-> url.com/advertisement/new
```

Refs:

- [Custom controller ref](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use)
- [Singular resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

---

The convention is to keep `resources` as a plural as it denotes the [HTTP "resources" directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_resource); IE that your `advertisements` are multiple resources which can be invoked by sending certain requests.

The problem you have is that Rails infers the path from the object, so you'll have something like...

```
<%= form_for @advertisement
```

... Rails will take the model name and create the standard route of `advertisements_path`.

--

Using the above routes should fix the issue (apart from the top one). Also explicitly setting the `url` of the `form` will work:

```
<%= form_for @advertisement, url: advertisement_path do |f| %>
```